# How to run executable as Administrator via Command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to start an exe from the command line running as Administrator, is that possible to do from a non-elevated cmd prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command to impersonate a user.

Answer (score -1):

`psexec` and `-h` option is the way to do it:

```
-h         If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
           run with the account's elevated token, if available.
```

I don't know of any other way to do that using built-in tools.